# How do I inform users a doccommented magic method can throw an Exception?

Tags: php

I have a doccomment on a class like so:

```php
/**
 * @method Response\FooResponse foo(Parameters\FooParameters $parameters)
 */
class Foo
{
}
```

This method can throw a `FooException`. How do I indicate this in the doccomment?

Comment: Note for close-voters - this does not already have an answer - the linked answer concerns a first class method not a method annotation.

Comment: The Documentation [On the phpDocs website](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/throws.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't believe that shows how to use it for a method annotation, only for a 'real' method

Comment: OK, reopened for you, not my DV

Comment: I added `class` under the example to hopefully make the context a little clearer at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use PHPDoc's [@throws](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/throws.html) in the docblock to specify which kind of exception might occur in that method.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you showed the OP that coded into his docblock

Comment: I know that exists but I don't know how to bring it into a `@method` annotation specifically. I couldn't find that documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since JSDocs are similar in definitions, you can use `@throws`. Check this article for reference:
https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#throwstag